# problem with \hline when creating a table

Tags: tables

Hi I am creating a table but am having trouble inserting a horizontal line at the base of my line. My code is:

```
\documentclass[11pt, oneside, a4paper]{book}

\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\usepackage{amsmath} 
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, left=1.5in, right=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{rotating} 
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[justification=centering]{caption}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage[]{natbib}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[L]{\nouppercase{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot{}
\linespread{1.3}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[h]
\small
\centering
\begin{tabular} { >{\centering\arraybackslash} m{4cm} | >{\centering\arraybackslash} m{4cm} | >{\centering\arraybackslash} m{2cm} | >{\centering\arraybackslash} m{2cm} }
\bfseries{Model} & \bfseries{Description} & \bfseries{x} & \bfseries{x} \\ \hline
x & x & x& x\\ 
\end{tabular}
\caption{x}
\label{x}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

when I take the `\hline` command out it works and appears to be the problem, how do I get the horizontal line to be drawn?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: Just a remark: use `\textbf{Model}` instead of `\bfseries{Model}`. `\bfseries` is a switch and has to be used like `{\bfseries Model}`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no error in your code.

You just have to load the `arydshln` package after `array` and `longtable`, as stated in its manual:

> Only one caution given to users of `array` (v2.3m or later) and `longtable` (v4.10 or later)
>   packages, included in Standard LaTeX Tools Bundle, and `colortab` and `colortbl` package is
>   that `arydshln` has to be loaded after `array`, `longtable`, `colortab` and/or `colortbl` done.